# guardar en un string una cadena

Tags: java

debo recibir por consola un dato de tipo string y guardarlo en una variable

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String palabra=scan.next();
System.out.println(palabra);
```

y despues mostrar esa cadena por la misma consola, el ejemplo seria ingresar por consola :

```
a pedro no le gustan las manzanas
```

hay espacios en el mensaje y pues no se como hacer para que se guarde toda la cadena en un mismo string

Answer (score 3):

El método `next()` solo recogerá el dato hasta que encuentre un espacio, lo demás que has escrito en la línea lo ignora por completo.

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String palabra=scan.next(); //primer espacio encontrado y lo demás es ignorado.
System.out.println(palabra);
```

> Entrada : Es un día genial para aprender
>
> > Salida: Es

Existe otro método que hace algo similar, pero en lugar de tomar el valor hasta que encuentre un espacio, toma todo hasta que encuentre un salto de línea (presiones la tecla <kbd>Intro</kbd> o <kbd>Enter</kbd>), esto lo puede realizar con `nextLine()`

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String line=scan.nextLine(); //toma hasta el salto de línea
System.out.println(line);
```

> Entrada : Es un día genial para aprender
>
> > Salida: Es un día genial para aprender

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String linea;
linea = sc.nextLine(); 
/*next() solo te recoge la primera palabra que escribas, con nextLine(), recoge toda la 
linea que escribas*/
System.out.println(linea);
```

Comment: Dale una breve explicación, para que lo entienda mejor.

Comment: Disculpa, acabo de llegar y apenas me manejo con esto, ire mejorando con el tiempo :)